# Sugar lager/cider brewing

Tags: sugar, priming-sugar, beginner, adjuncts, adjunct

What, if any, is the difference between brewing sugar and priming sugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, no difference at all in the kinds of sugar. The difference could be made that "brewing sugar" is added at the stage of the boil, and "priming sugar" is added at bottling time, for carbonation.

However, all sugars used are either

- glucose (or dextrose, different name, same product), which is sometimes sold under the name of "brewing sugar"
- sucrose, table sugar, which is chemically somewhat more complex than glucose
- invert sugar, which is sucrose that has been chemically split into glucose and fructose, this is a syrup

Variants of sucrose are castor sugar, cane sugar, demerara sugar, etc, mostly anything crystallised.

Variants of invert sugar are honey, and different syrups that are sold in the homebrew store, also maple and agave syrup.

Variants of sucrose and invert sugars can contain differing amounts of other by-products of sugar production, like caramel, molasses or unfiltered residue from the production process. These define the taste and the colour of the resulting end products.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info!